# Obtain arbitrary number of matches in perl

Tags: regex, perl, match

I have some perl code that looks as such:

```
my @matches = $text =~ /^!random ([0-9]+?)d([0-9]+?)([+-][0-9]+?)*$/i
```

where text is a string that contains some arbitrary text (that I received from an IRC server. Theoretically, this should get all of the matches, but it only stores match group 1, group 2, and the last match of 3. So if $text contained "!random 3d4+5-6", the matches would be "3", "4", and "6". How can I make it so that the matches would be "3", "4", "+5", "-6"? Note that I have also tried the regex with /gim as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than include the characters you don't want in the match, just perform a global match on a single number pattern, with the plus or minus being optional.

```
my $text = "!random 3d4+5-6";
my @matches = $text =~ /((?:\+|-)?\d)/g;
print "@matches";
# 3 4 +5 -6
```

https://eval.in/313604

---

*Explanation:*

Match a single digit number `\d`.

Preceded by a plus or minus, `+` or `-`. Parenthesis `()` and pipes `|` can be used for alternation, that is when you want this or that. Separate all the alternatives with pipes: `(+|-)`.

`+` is an operator so must escape: `(\+|-)`.

Don't allow the parenthesis used for alternation to capture a value by including `?:` immediately after first paren, now looks like `(?:\+|-)`.

Make that whole thing optional `?`. Now looks like `(?:\+|-)?`.

Put those together: `(?:\+|-)?\d`.

And capture that: `((?:\+|-)?\d)`.

Make it a global match `//g` to capture all occurrences: `/((?:\+|-)?\d)/g`.